# Is there a dependency management tool/library for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dependency-management

Is there a dependency management tool/library for JavaScript?

PHP has [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/) and [Packagist](http://packagist.org/).

Ruby on Rails has [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/).

What is available for JavaScript?

Comment: If your are using grails by chance, it has built-in support for JS (and all other client side) deps mgmt via the resource plugin.

Comment: @techfoobar thanks for the info, however I am not using Grails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Bower](https://github.com/bower/bower).

You can specify a `components.json` file which contains all the dependencies for your project.

Answer (score 3):

There is [npm](https://npmjs.org/) for nodejs and [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) for dependency management in the browser.